# React Material UI ListItems Vertical Align

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to populate ListItems( ListItemIcon and ListItemText) on Material UI mini Drawer in vertical align mode. Some how my ListItemText not aligning properly to the ListItemIcons.

Here is my styles:

```
  link: {
    textDecoration: "none",
    "&:hover, &:focus": {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.yellow
    }
  },
  linkActive: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.light
  },
  linkIcon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(4),
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary + "99",
    transition: theme.transitions.create("color"),
    width: 24,
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  linkText: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary + "CC",
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["opacity", "color"]),
    fontSize: 13,
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  }
```

Component

```
import React from "react";
import {
  ListItem,
  ListItemIcon,
  ListItemText,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import classnames from "classnames";

// styles
import useStyles from "./styles";

export default function SidebarLink({
  link,
  icon,
  label,
  location,
}) {
  var classes = useStyles();
  var isLinkActive =
    link &&
    (location.pathname === link || location.pathname.indexOf(link) !== -1);

  return (
    <ListItem
      button
      component={link && Link}
      to={link}
      className={classes.link}
    >
      <ListItemIcon
        className={classnames(classes.linkIcon, {
          [classes.linkIconActive]: isLinkActive
        })}
      >
        {icon}
      </ListItemIcon>

      <ListItemText
        classes={{
          primary: classnames(classes.linkText, {
            [classes.linkIconActive]: isLinkActive
          })
        }}
        primary={label}
      ></ListItemText>
    </ListItem>
  );
}
```

[image]

How to align ListItems in vertical mode properly? I tried adding textAlign and alignItems to center to linkText css class but not them worked.

Any Help is Appreciated

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

react-router-dom Link uses html < a > tag under the hood. 
< a > children will be displayed in column as default. 
You just need to style your link properly:

```
  link: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    textDecoration: "none",
    "&:hover, &:focus": {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.yellow
    }
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for the code.. but still icon and text are not aligned to center properly.

Comment: Changing flexDirection: 'row' to column fixed the issue